# OrientDB – Graph Visualization related questions?

Tags: graph, visualization, orientdb

OrientDB Version: 2.2.0-beta2

Hello Everyone,

Use case we are working on, is giving user access to Graph Visualization and hide the complexity of the query via Javascript function. Ex:

```
SQL: SELECT FROM COUNTRY WHERE NAME=’CANADA’
Function: SELECT findCountry(‘CANADA’)
```

Now, users are asking questions if there is a way to adjust the look n feel of the graph visualization.

I am looking for your suggestions as an advice or point to some kind of document?

1. Most of our data is in hierarchy format – Is it possible instead of circles, we display data in org-chart format or pure right to left?
2. Also, instead of circle can we use another other shape? i.e. rectangle or triangle? Depend on the class.
3. Possible to word-wrap the label in the circle?
4. Possible to show multiple properties in the circle? i.e. ID + Name
5. Possible to change the Stroke colour based on the property in the class ex: If the City is also the capital then can the stroke color to RED and size to 5 but keep the fill color same as other cities?
6. Any way to undo on the Graph tool? Ex: if we are doing drill down from 1 > 2 > 3 > 4 and undo 4 and back to number 3?

Really appreciate your thoughts.

regards

Comment: Hi RLx, for your request for enhancement you can open an issue on github

Comment: Thanks will do. Do you any thought if above is possible today? Can you point me to some examples or documentations?

Comment: You can see at http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Graph-Editor.html